# Javascript window location cookie previous page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, redirect

So a website i'm developing in Wordpress will redirect to /welcome/ and once the dob is entered the page redirects back to the root page. However if I was to visit the /about/ page from a search engine it'll redirect to the /welcome/ on enter the DOB it'll redirect back to the root. I am however looking to have it redirect to the previous page so if it was /about/ once you've entered the DOB /welcome/ will redirect to /about/.

I've some code here but looking to make it dynamic if at all possible?

```
var thecookie = jQuery.cookie('agecheck');

if(thecookie =='remember'){
window.location.replace("/");
}

if(thecookie =='forget'){
window.location.replace("/");

}
```

I have tried window.history.back(-2) and the likes but doesn't seem to work cross browser?

Anyone got any advice on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per your requirement you can store window.location.pathname variable to local storage of browser when you redirect for asking DOB. When you come to root page you can check whether local storage has previous location stored if it's there you can redirect it to the location it has.

before you redirect to root page :

```
localStorage.setItem('location', window.location.pathname);
```

on root page check if there is some localStorage value avalible or not :

```
var temp = localStorage.getItem('location');
if(temp){
 window.location.replace(temp);
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks so much.